# Cannot install Beautiful Soup to Python 2 as I already had it installed in my Python 3, but I cannot import or uninstall it either

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have recently had to revert back to Python 2.7 for work in ArcMap. I tried to install Beautiful Soup but as I had it installed already within Python 3, it claims the 'Requirement Already Satisfied'; however, I cannot import any of the modules because of course, it is installed in Python 3 and not within Python 2.

I have tried to uninstall and again, it cannot find it. Catch 22.

**Attempted install -**

```
d:\egm722>pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\geo\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (4.6.3)

**Attempted imports -**

> > > import bs4
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named bs4
> > >       from bs4 import beautifulsoup
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named bs4

**Attempted Uninstall -**

d:\egm722>pip uninstall BeautifulSoup 
Skipping BeautifulSoup as it is not installed.

I'd rather not revert back to Python 3 and uninstall from there, so any advice on how to do it in my current state would be much appreciated. I'm a novice when it comes to Python, especially different environments, so go easy on me.

Comment: You should be able to install Python2 and Python3 separately without any problems. What happens when you type `which pip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be specific which `pip` you want to use, to make sure you use the one associated with your Python 2 installation. Try either:

```
pip2 install beautifulsoup4
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or, if Python 2 is the default python on your system, you can just run

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: If your Python 2 is the default command found when you type "python", you can just use that instead of "python2". What's really important is just that you refer to the correct python/pip when running the install command.

Comment: Both of those not recognised as an internal or external command etc.

Comment: @LeePowell Then how are you running python above to get the import error?

Comment: python -m pip install beautifulsoup4 worked. the -m made the difference. Why is that? Correction, it may have been that I wasn't putting python at the beginning. Total schoolboy. Thanks for that, will mark as accepted.

Comment: @LeePowell It means run a script that comes installed with your python distribution by default. If `pip` and `python` for some reason point to different installs of python, then `pip` and `python -m pip` will have different results. To be safe, I always do `python -m pip` so I can be sure which version of python I am installing for.